# TYPO3 Extension with composer not working

Tags: dependencies, typo3, composer-php

We created a typo3 distribution and it have two dependency extensions such as powermail and realurl. For now, dependencies are placed into our distribution extension under the folder \Initialisation. We need to change this by adding the composer.json to install the dependencies. So we have created a composer.json file and placed inside the distribution and tried to install the distribution in a fresh TYPO3 installation. But we are getting the following screen:

[image: typo3-install-distribution]

The following screen is composer.json:

[image: extension-composer-json]

**Where we are going wrong?**

**Question:** Is TYPO3 will automatically run the composer.json(which present inside the distribution)  while installing a TYPO3 Distribution?

Comment: Did you install the distribution via TYPO3 backend?

Comment: Could you update the Extension Manager extension list by switching the select field in the top to "Get Extensions"? Maybe this is solving your issue already.

Comment: @ThomasLöffler Yes, i tried to install my distribution through TYPO3 backend -> Extension

Answer (score 0):

`composer.json` files are used by composer to collect packages from packagist or another satis instalation. If these packages are the type TYPO3 extension the TYPO3 composer installer will put them in the `typo3conf/ext` folder. The extensions are not activated yet!  You can do this from the Extension Manager or from the command line with the typo3 console. 
If you install an extension from the Extension Manager the EM will try to install the dependencies from TER (if it is not present yet) for which it needs the data from the TER extension list.

To let others install your ext from the EM, put the dependencies in `ext_emconf.php` and for people who use composer put them in `composer.json`.

Comment: Hi, i have added the dependencies in ext_emconf.php. But it's not get installed from the EM. I don't know, where i am going wrong.